# What request should I use from my ESP32 to discover MQTT resources on a mosquitto broker on raspbery pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, iot, esp32

I would like to be able from a ESP32 MQTT client to discover all the resources available on a raspberry pi running mosquitto broker.

Searched the internet and checked my ESP32 MQTT broker client for clues but found none.

Hi, I used the ter discovery because that is the term used in CoAp to scan the server for service but what I want to achieve is to find all services available at the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "discover all resources on a MQTT broker". You don't query brokers, you subscribe to a topic, and if a message is published you get it.

Comment: // , Are you perhaps asking how you would find all of the available topics to which to subscribe? This might work better as a forum post somewhere, since it might be one of Stack Overflow's catch-22s where you have to know something to ask about that thing, and vice versa.

Could you rewrite this a bit, @Paulo, for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of querying an MQTT broker.

The client connects and subscribes to 1 or more topics and the broker will deliver any messages published with those topics to the client.

Subscriptions can be to exact topics or to topic patterns including the wildcard characters '+' (which matches a single level in a topic) or '#' (which matches all subsequent levels in a topic).

If you want to receive all messages published on a broker then you can subscribe to a pattern of just '#'.

Comment: Hi, it definitively answer my question. subscribing to '#' is the solution I was looking for. Thanks hardillb.